# What PHP design pattern is used to allow classes which don't extend each other have access to each others properties

Tags: php

I have a class: site_info, which loads the site configurations parameters.

I also have a router class, a user class and a search class. The search class requires the properties and methods from the user class, router class and site_info, but at present router class extends site_info, search class extends site_info and user extends site_info.

Should I instead have site_info, user class and router all in a single class and then have search class extend this class? Or is there a better way.

Each of these classes are represented by class instances and site_info is overloaded with an array into the constructor to populate some of the class properties.

Comment: Just use setters and getters.

Comment: @Daan So if I am inside an instance of the user class, the router class instance won't be defined so how do I use a router getter in that case? I do know what getters and setters are. Thanks.

Comment: Make an instance of router class in user class maybe?

Comment: @Daan So every class that needs to access the router and isn't an extension of it, needs to make an instance of the router class? I'm not sure if that is the best approach but I appreciate the input.

Comment: No only 1 instance would be enough for all classes. There isn't another approach unless you use alot of static methods in which you don't need to instantiate the class. How do you think major frameworks do this ?

Comment: @daan Sorry, I think I am misunderstanding something important. If I make an instance of the router class in the user class ($router_instance), how can the search class then access $router_instance because $router_instance wont' defined? Or is the correct approach to make an instance of the router class outside of the user and search classes and pass this same instance into both classes via their constructors? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you might want to look at dependency injection.

Comment: Your last question would be okay it's called dependency injection like @MartinBean said.

Comment: imo, Couple of choices - make `site info` as a `singleton` or 'inject it' into everything that need it. If you go the 'singleton' appraoch then ensure that it can be easily cleared and reloaded with different data for testing purposes.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thank you. Is there any chance you could give me an example based on what I provided. I've googled and it seems to be what I want but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example no inheritance or instances whatsoever (and still able to get a private property):

```
Class MyClass {

    private static $myProperty = "test";
    public static function getProp(){
        return self::$myProperty;
    }   

}

Class MyOtherClass {

    public static function getProperty(){
        return MyClass::getProp();
    }

}

echo MyOtherClass::getProperty(); //Echos test
```

Comment: Thanks. Am I right though, this doesn't work with class instances does it? Which is important to me since I am heavily using instances.